# How does a virtual machine connect to the Internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, internet, wireshark

I have a virtual machine running Kali Linux on VirtualBox, with the host OS being Windows 10, and it can connect to my Wi-Fi network — however, the network settings in Kali Linux displays “Wired Connection.”

I know this has something to do with the fact that the virtual machine emulates a wired connection. How exactly does this work?

I'm specifically asking because I'm attempting to capture loopback packets on Wireshark in the Kali Linux machine, which cannot be done on Windows, but it doesn't seem to be working. I want to know if this has something to do with the fact that the VM is using the Windows connection.

Comment: Almost all of the "hardware" a VM uses is virtualized. You *could* redirect a WiFi USB dongle to the VM; maybe that would give you what you need.

Comment: How it works is complicated. Depends on your software, and setup.  Sometimes TCP is emulated.  Sometimes networking acts like bridging. Popular emulation software provides multiple options. I see this question tagged with VirtualBox which I don't happen to have conveniently installed at the moment, so no full answer right now.  But all that has to do with the virtual "network port" hardware.  The Loopback is more of an "operating system" feature, part of the operating system, and so is not really affected by these settings in the "virtual machine" software.  So the vm software isn't the cause.

Comment: with hyper-v you can create a "virtual switch" and then choose which vm's connect to it. And then you have the option to give that virtual switch outside connectivity or not. If you choose to give it outside access it ties into the network card of the host machine.